# Passing an array by pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

How do i get the size of array in `void Func(int (*a)[5])` for loop condition and print elements?

```
void Func(int (*a)[5])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      cout << a[i]; // doesn't work
}

int main()
{
   int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   Func(&a);
}
```

Comment: You don't - not possible

Comment: @JT (a very annoying tag, BTW) Not generally possible would be more accurate :-)

Comment: I wonder whats the use of `int (*a)[5]` if its not workable.

Comment: It is just history from the C language. You can use arrays as parameter types, but it decays to pointers anyway.  If you use C++ you should use a std::vector which knows its own size.

Comment: You may want to read our [array FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the way you access the array is wrong. Inside your function you have a *pointer* to an array. The pointer has to be dereferenced first, before you use the `[]` operator on it

```
void Func(int (*a)[5])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      cout << (*a)[i];
}
```

Secondly, i don't understand why you need to "get" the size of the array, when the size is fixed at compile time, i.e. it is always 5. But in any case you can use the well-known `sizeof` trick

```
void Func(int (*a)[5])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof *a / sizeof **a; i++)
      cout << (*a)[i];
}
```

The `sizeof *a / sizeof **a` expression is guaranteed to evaluate to 5 in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Using a function template would be better if you major emphasis is on passing the size of the array.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void Func(T (&a)[N])
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
      cout << a[i]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you didn't de-reference it enough. You have a pointer to an array- the pointer requires de-referencing, *and* the array needs indexing.

```
void Func(int (*a)[5])
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      std::cout << (*a)[i];
}

int main()
{
   int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   Func(&a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array into a function, it degrades to a pointer and all size information is lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use a STL container, like vector, to make things easier.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void Func(vector <int> a){
   for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
   cout << a[i];
}

int main (){
       int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
       vector<int> a (nums, nums + sizeof(nums) / sizeof(int) );
       Func(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do i get the size of array

You already know the size at compile-time, it's 5. You just forgot to dereference the pointer:

```
cout << (*a)[i];
```

Comment: What about `int size = sizeof(*a)/sizeof(int);`?

Comment: @user: You already told the compiler that you point to an array of 5 integers. What else do you hope to find out about the array? Yes, `sizeof(*a)/sizeof(int)` will yield 5, but again, you already know that.

Answer (score -1):

```
void Func(int * a)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      cout << *(a+i);
}

int main()
{
   int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   Func(a);
}
```